# How to access button of bootstrap modal launched dynamically from a different html file using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have written a code to dynamically launch a bootstrap modal from another html file (testrecord.html) using java script.

The bootstrap modal contains a close button. I would like to add a java script in main html file that access the close button of the modal launched from testrecord.html file. I want to close the bootstrap modal on click of close button present in the modal footer. I tried different ways but none worked. I also referred to similar questions but none of the solutions could solve my issue. kindly help.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='teststyle.css'>
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="testrecord.html" id="buttonCustom2">
        Create Record
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="recordContent" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg ">
            <div class="modal-content"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#buttonCustom2").on('click', function (e) {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                $(".modal-content").html('<object data="' + url + '"/>');
                $('#recordContent').modal('show')
                $('#recordContent').getElementById('closeButton').on('click', function(){
                    $('#recordContent').modal('hide')
                });
            });
        });    
    </script>
</html>
```

**testrecord.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='teststyle.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal-header">    
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Content</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        hello  check modal body here
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="closeButton">Close</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the boostrap distribution [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)  so it works

Comment: This is for modal in the same html file..I want to launch a modal from another html file and access the button

Comment: Indeed the issue is in your main.html file...

Comment: Could you explain what is the isue in the main html file which is not making it work..could you suggest any alternative which can make it work

Comment: You should separate your scripts from your html. What does the final html look like? `data-bs-dismiss` should be enough to hide the modal, no need to call hide explicitly. [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo)